# Best way to animate an Accordion type bar?

Tags: javascript, html, css

First see live demo here: http://khill.mhostiuckproductions.com/siteLSSBoilerPlate/

Clicking BUTTON at the middle of my topbar, expands a section which contains content.  As it stands this expansion does not animate.

Given the code and the jsfiddle below, what is the best way to animate this?  I would prefer to use CSS transitions.  I'm not worried about mobile as my mobile version this BUTTON is hidden and can not be clicked.

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/HXVxs/

**Javascript:**

```
<script language="javascript"> 
    function toggle() {
        var ele = document.getElementById("toggleText");
        var text = document.getElementById("displayText");
        if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";
            text.innerHTML = "BUTTON";
        }
        else {
            ele.style.display = "block";
            text.innerHTML = "BUTTON";
        }
    } 
    </script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- BUTTON PLACED IN MY TOP BAR -->
<div class="topbar">
<div class="company-list top-border"><a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Click here to display customer list.</a></div>
</div>


<!-- TOP WIDGET (different from top-bar, placed above top-bar in my HTML structure) -->

<div class="top-widget">
<div class="company-list-toggle bottom-border" id="toggleText" style="display: none">

    <p>Sample text here...</p>

<div class="company-list top-border"><a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">Click here to display customer list.</a></div>

</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.top-widget { /* tried CSS3 transitions here and did not work */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    background: #2b332a;
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT: A quick note... A standard accordion does not fix my issue.  The reasoning for this is that a standard accordion displays it's contents on-click of the containing div element.  In my situation, the BUTTON that displays the content div on-click, is separate from the content-div itself.  Adapting a regular accordion will not work for this situation, or I would have done that from the get go.

Thanks again!

Comment: You can easily done this with jQuery animate but if you still wanna go with JS then you have to write your own code to animate.

Comment: I am completely open to suggestions, how would I go about doing this with jQuery animate?  I would still prefer to see if anyone has a CSS solution first.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `height` (toggling between 0 and `scrollHeight`) and a CSS transition: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HXVxs/1/)

Comment: You're fiddle is not working on my end, not sure why.  Can you double check?

Comment: Depends on your browser. The Fiddle only supports IE10 and Firefox. You can add support for Chrome by adding `-webkit-transition:height 1s ease`. Older versions of IE do not support transitions, but I consider this unimportant since it's not the end of the world if something doesn't slide.

Comment: D'oh! Of course, I didn't even catch that.  This is exactly what I needed!  Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

As a random example, look at:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-accordion-menu-jquery/

The jQuery solution does not mean you lose the CSS control, quite the opposite. I worked with "accordions" quite a bit, they work great in jQuery. Browser compatibility is pretty good as well.

Comment: Do you see a [tag:jQuery] tag there?

Comment: Unfortunately this does not quite work for my situation. Reasoning: the button that displays the content div initially is outside of the div that displays the content.  This solution assumes that I am able to click on the DIV that will eventually expand, which I can not.  They are separate divs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an accordion that has good style and animation http://jqueryui.com/accordion/ . Check the examples on the side of the page. You can view the source code clicking the 'view source', bottom of the page.

Comment: Because, of course, [jQuery is the answer to everything](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif).

Comment: As with the solution above...

Unfortunately this does not quite work for my situation. Reasoning: the button that displays the content div initially is outside of the div that displays the content.  This solution assumes that I am able to click on the DIV that will eventually expand, which I can not.  They are separate divs.